# Nested population returns a json type in pug template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug

Nested populate is resulting in a json output in pug - when I need it in normal string format.
My function is here -

```
    function getStoryByIdInsideCommunity(req, res, next) {

  const companyName= req.params.companyName
  const storyId = req.params.storyId

  console.log(companyName)

  Club.findOne({
    clubName: companyName
  }, (err, club) => {
    if (err || !club) return res.status(404).json()

    const clubId = club._id
    console.log(club, club._id)

    Story.findOne({ companyName: clubId, _id: storyId })
    .populate({ path: 'user' })
    .populate(
      { 
        path: 'comments',
        model: 'Comment', 
          populate: { 
            model: 'User' ,
            path: 'user',
            select: {"name":1, _id: 0}
          } 
      
    })
    .exec()
      .then((story) => {

        res.render('story_single', {
          story,
          club,
          title: `${story.title.slice(0,50)} | Story & Experiences | ${club.companyName.name} companyName`
        });

      })
  })
};
```

I am then printing it like this :

```
each comment,i in story.comments
  h6.col-12.comments-text= comment.content
  | by 
    span.list-all-title= comment.user
```

And my page displays this :
Comment Body by { name: 'John Doe' }

How do I drop the {name:} and just have John Doe print ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `comment.user` is an object with a `name` property. To output the name replace `comment.user` with `comment.user.name`.

```
span.list-all-title= comment.user.name
```